# Can I transfer data from form to block without page reload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

There are the form and the block at the one page where data transferred from form and at the same time data save to the database. I don't know how I can realize it, but I have created this code:

```js
$("#formbutton").click(function(event) {
  $("#tbodyid").load("#tbodyid", "#tbodyid", '');
});
```

Comment: Where is the server script url you are sending request to save data to database?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of click use submit after $(tag).